# Looping over list in python and appending the result in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code like below,

```
from io import StringIO
a = """ab: 01dvfgf
cd: 01fgvr windows
ab: 02hjuy linux
cd: 01erttt windows
lm: 02hjkkk"""
s = StringIO(a)
a_01 = []
a_02 =[]
zone = ['01', '02']
for elements in zone:
    for line in s:
        if line[4:6] == '01':
            a_01.append(line) 
        elif line[4:6] == '02':
            a_02.append(line)

print('a_01', *a_01, sep = "\n")
print('a_02', *a_02, sep = "\n")
```

In this code can I replace below 4 lines into two so that I don't have to write it again and again for different zones

```
if line[4:6] == '01':
    a_01.append(line) 
elif line[4:6] == '02':
    a_02.append(line)
```

something like:

```
if line[4:6] == elements:
    "a_" + elements.append(line)
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: I am getting the result with the code I shared, I just want to improve my code (shorten my code)

Comment: Instead of declaring separate variables such as `a_01`, `a_02` etc, use a `dict` of `list`s, i.e. `a = {'01': [], '02': []}`

Comment: so how do I append in that case

Comment: You can just put the `a_01` and `a_02` lists into the dictionary. They don't have to stop being independent variables, they should just *also* live somewhere you can easily index them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
...
s = StringIO(a)
zones = defaultdict(list)
for line in s:
    zones[line[4:6]].append(line)

for zone, lines in zones.items():  # can be iterated just as a regular dict
    print(zone, *lines, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dict` to store the values.

```py
from io import StringIO
a = """ab: 01dvfgf
cd: 01fgvr windows
ab: 02hjuy linux
cd: 01erttt windows
lm: 02hjkkk"""
s = StringIO(a)

zone_dict = {'01': list(), '02': list()}
for line in s:
    #print(line)
    for key in zone_dict.keys():
        #print(key)
        if line[4:6] == key:
            zone_dict[key].append(line)
zone_dict
```

**Output**:

```
{'01': ['ab: 01dvfgf\n', 'cd: 01fgvr windows\n', 'cd: 01erttt windows\n'],
 '02': ['ab: 02hjuy linux\n', 'lm: 02hjkkk']}
```